# Combine awk commands into perl or python

Tags: python, perl, awk

I'm relativity new using command line to manipulate files. 
I have a very large text file and I need to extract certain lines from the file. 
I can do this with awk

```
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleA") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleA.txt
```

I would like to do this for many Samples at the same time and not have to wait for each to finish on the command line, can I write a perl or python script to do this?  I have run perl and python scripts others have written but have not written any of my own.

Want to do

```
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleA") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleA.txt
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleB") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleB.txt
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleC") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleC.txt
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleC") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleD.txt
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleE") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleE.txt
awk -F '\t' '{ if ($1 == "SampleF") print $0}' PatientID.txt > SampleF.txt
```

AND then concatenate all of the SampleX.txt files into one file.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The files are too large to add a sample. I essentially want to extract lines from the PatientID.txt file where the first column value matches a given value.  Print all of those lines to a new file.

Comment: yes, you can write a perl or python script to do this.

Comment: Could you show me an example? I'm not sure how to put these awk commands into either perl or python.

Comment: You can also do it in a single awk script. Look up how to print to a file instead of standard outout in an awk manual.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do the same with ease

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$1~/^Sample[A-F]$/{print > ($1".txt")}' PatientID.txt
$ cat Sample{A..F}.txt > SampleX.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will this work when my sample names are not sequential like Sample A, B, C, D etc?  I have over 300 samples and the names are like a bar code.  example xx27-03-A10X and xx27-7A-73F0

Comment: there are better ways to handle that case, your question should be descriptive of your actual problem.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question.  I have a very large file with data for thousands of samples. I would like to extract data for a set of samples IDs contained in the large file.  How can I extract data that is specific for a list of sample IDs?